# Creating data frame in R using variable

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have two data types price of type list and company of type character

```
price
[[1]]
[1] "Rp 83.000"

[[2]]
[1] "Rp 87.900"

[[3]]
[1] "Rp92,000"

[[4]]
[1] "Regular price  125,000.00 Discount price  125,000.00 "
```

and

```
company
[1] "Tororo"     "Babyzania"  "Bilna"      "Babylonish"
```

I want to create a data frame using the two data types and of the form :

> Tororo   Rp 83.00
>
> Babyzania Rp 87.900
>
> Bilna Rp 92,00
>
> Babylonish Regular price  125,000.00 Discount price  125,000.00

Can anyone help me out i tried using directly

```
df=data.frame(company,price)
```

But it is not giving the correct dataframe I want.

Comment: Try to unlist() the price variable first. It's not a vector like company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list is exactly the same length and in the same order as your company name vector you can do this

```
df = data.frame(company, unlist(price))
```

Your 4th price is very different from the top 3 so you wont get what you printed anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this approach:

The data:

```
price <- list("Rp 83.000", "Rp 87.900", "Rp92,000",
              "Regular price  125,000.00 Discount price  125,000.00 ")
company <- c("Tororo", "Babyzania", "Bilna", "Babylonish")
```

Use regular expressions to create the price strings:

```
price2 <- sub(".*?([0-9.,]+) *$", "Rp \\1", unlist(price))
# [1] "Rp 83.000"     "Rp 87.900"     "Rp 92,000"     "Rp 125,000.00"
```

Create data frame:

```
data.frame(company, price = price2)
#      company         price
# 1     Tororo     Rp 83.000
# 2  Babyzania     Rp 87.900
# 3      Bilna     Rp 92,000
# 4 Babylonish Rp 125,000.00
```

Comment: For Babylonish price output should belike this "Regular price  125,000.00 Discount price  125,000.00 "

Comment: @HimaanshuGauba You changed the expected output *after* I posted my question.

Comment: sorry actually I mistakenly wrote the wrong output for Babylonish

Comment: @HimaanshuGauba You don't need to apply `sub`. The function `unlist` is sufficient.